# Task updates record in DB only ones

Tags: python, django, celery

I have a periodic task that I run every minute and I can't figure out why it updates field that I specify in query only the first time I run it. When I'm changing the value after the first execution of task, it's not changing back to 0. Here's the task:

```
@shared_task
class my_task():
    one_day_before = timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    User.objects.filter(status=1, created__lt=one_day_before).update(status=0)
```

And here's what I see in celery worker output when it runs:

```
[2014-11-23 14:38:34,213: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: users.tasks.my_task[fe16a6e9-0b2c-4099-9e95-29c8501d500a]
[2014-11-23 14:38:34,216: INFO/MainProcess] Task users.tasks.my_task[fe16a6e9-0b2c-4099-9e95-29c8501d500a] succeeded in 0.00161398899945s: <users.tasks.my_task instance at 0x7fd54e12f1b8>
```

So could you please tell me where I'm wrong? I just can't make it work.

Comment: Outside of celery the query works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't even understand why I could make such mistake. Of course it must be described as function (not as class):

```
@shared_task
def my_task():
    one_day_before = timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    User.objects.filter(status=1, created__lt=one_day_before).update(status=0)
```